# how to group rows based on a dates in a single column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of date (A1:CY7026) with a column for start dates. this column has a large amount of repeated dates within it. i need these dates group together based on the working week they are located in (eg. all values reading 16/7/18 - 22/07/18 would be one group and the following week would make up another).

Comment: use the built in sort function to sort ascending or descending based on that column.

Comment: use a pivot table

Answer (score 0):

Use below in B2 cell (Suppose you had a header column) and drag to the rest. Sort to obtain the desired result.

```
=CONCATENATE(YEAR(A2),"-",WEEKNUM(A2))
```

[image]